# Reduction of degrees of freedom in hamiltonian mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, degrees-of-freedom

How can the presence of a constant of motion in a Hamiltonian system reduce the number of degrees of freedom of the system?

The thing I don't understand is: the presence of a constant of motion reduces the number of degrees of freedom from $2n$ to $(2n-1)$ or from to $n$ to $(n-1)$ in a Hamiltonian system with $n$ degrees of freedom (so with a $2n$-dimensional phase space)?

Comment: Comment to the post (v4): Do you mean _constraint_ rather than _constant of motion?_

Comment: @Qmechanic No, but I will explain better: for example in a system with central symmetry there is rotational invariance. This leads to the conservation of the angular momentum. There are two independent constant if motion $L_x$ and $L_y$, the constant values of which impose constraints to the motion of the system. Isn't this a way to say that the system has two less degrees of freedom than before? What I want to understand is if for a general system with $2n$-dimensional phase space and $k$ constants of motion the degrees of freedom are reduced by $k$ (or if there are more assumptions to make)

Comment: @PPeg : I'm very interested in this topic. I asked a similar question, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/470986/hamiltonian-with-one-constant-of-motion-besides-the-hamiltonian-itself . The usual belief is that each constant of motion (besides the Hamiltonian itself) removes two variable = one degree of freedom from the system (see the answers to my question). This is never written explicitly in books but assumed to be true. However, I believe that there are exceptions to this. I would be pleased to discuss with you and know if you have any information to share.

Answer (score 2):

Consider any quantity '$f$' related to a classical system. As a classical system is completely described by $p_i$'s(generalized momenta) and $q_i$'s (generalized positions)  one can write this quantity in their terms. If such a quantity is a constant of motion it means that

$f(p_i,q_i)=C $

where C is some constant. Notice that this acts like a constraint equation. One can use this equation to solve for one of the generalized momenta or position in terms of the others, thus decreasing the degree of freedom of the whole system by one.

To give a simple example if one of the $p_i$'s is conserved say $p_1$ then

$p_1=k$

So this fixes one of the coordinates in your phase space and you have one less degree of freedom to work with in your Hamiltonian.

Comment: OK, and If there are two constants of motion the number of degrees of freedom is always reduced by two?

Comment: yes,  In fact if you have n constants of motion it is reduces by n.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is: the presence of a constant of motion reduces the number of degrees of freedom from 2n to (2n-1) or from to n to (n-1) in a Hamiltonian system with n degrees of freedom? (By that I mean a system with a 2n-dimensional phase space. I cannot find reference anywhere, it would be great if you could provide some.

Comment: There is this book I love to read, Its called 'Variational Principles of Mechanics' by Cornelius Lanczos. He has a very unique approach to Classical Mechanics. I am not sure If it will properly serve your purpose, but do give it a try.

Comment: In the book there are not enough explanations on what I'm looking for, but thank you. Do you have any idea on the question in my last comment?

Comment: Sorry, But It's not clear to me what you are asking. I thought I explained in my answer how the degree f freedoms are reduced.

Can you tell me what exactly did you not understand. Is there a problem with your understanding of what degree of freedom is?

Comment: The number $n$ of degrees of freedom is the minimum number of independent generalized positions required to describe the system. The phase space will be $2n$ dimensional, and the Hamiltonian system is a dynamical system of $2n$ (independent?) first order diff. equations. If $f=C$ is a constant of motion, you can write one of the $2n$ $q$ or $p$, put $q_1$, in terms of the other coordinates and $C$, so that $q_1$ is no more needed to describe the system. Now, from what I have understood from your answer, the dynamical system now has $2n-1$ equations left. (Next comment)

Comment: What about the number of degrees of freedom of the Hamiltonian system (as the number of independent generalized positions)? I am in the situation of having a $8n$-dimensional Hamiltonian system which I know that must be equivalent to a $2n$-dimensional one. To be so, I think that I have somehow to show that the firs system needs less than $4n$ positions to be described; the degrees of freedom must be reduced from $4n$ to $n$. How many constants of motion do I need? (Consider that the phase space is $8n$ dimensional in the first case, and $2n$ dimensional in the second). Thanks.